# Express: use separate route file for multiple kinds of http requests on same path

Tags: express

Here are my routes:

```
app.get('/signUp', routes.signUp);
app.post('/signUp' , routes.signUp);
```

Here is my separate file for routes.

```
exports.signUp = function(req, res) {
    res.render('signUp');
};
```

The second block of code is behaviour I want in response to a get request.

How do I respond to a post request? I have already tied up the signUp function with behaviour that responds to get. Do I bundle up the post behaviour in the same function and render the sign up page again? Suppose I simply want to render the view, I don't want the post behaviour to execute in that case so it would be strange to bundle those together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the express router module should resolve this for you.

route file -

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route("/")
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.render('signUp');
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    //do something else 
  })

module.exports = router
```

index.js/app.js/server.js/whatever you call it.

```
//..

signUp = require("./routes/signup.js"); //or wherever this is

//... 

app.use("/signUp", signUp);

//..
```

Comment: This module does exactly what I need. Thanks.